# Show that double sequence $a_{m,n} = b_{m} + c_{n}$ converges iff $b_{m}$ and $c_{n}$ converge

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have come to a problem in a multivariate calculus book that I have a question about. The problem goes :

> Let $(b_{n})$ and $(c_{n})$ be sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Define a double sequence
> $(a_{m,n})$ by $a_{m,n} := b_{m} + c_{n}$ for $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}$. Show that
> $(a_{m,n})$ is convergent if and only if both $(b_{m})$ and $(c_{n})$ are convergent.
> (Hint : Cauchy Criterion)

After reading the comments I have decided to edit this post. I have attempted another solution. I would like to know if there are any problems with it that anyone can see. The solution is below :

We can first prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists (m_{0},n_{0}) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}$ such that :
\begin{equation} \tag{1}\label{1}
| a_{m,n} - a_{p,q} | < \epsilon \; \forall (m,n), (p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0}) 
\end{equation}
if $(b_{n})$ and $(c_{n})$ are convergent. We see :
\begin{align}
\eqref{1}  
 & \Leftrightarrow | (b_{m} + c_{n}) - (b_{p} + c_{q}) | < \epsilon \; \forall (m,n),(p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0}) \\
 & \Leftrightarrow | (b_{m} - b_{p}) + (c_{n} - c_{q}) | < \epsilon \; \forall (m,n),(p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0})
\end{align}
Since $(b_{m})$ and $(c_{n})$ are Cauchy, we know that for any $\beta > 0$ :
\begin{equation} \tag{2}\label{2}
\exists m_{0} \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } |b_{m} - b_{p}| < \beta \; \forall m,p \geq m_{0} 
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{equation} \tag{3}\label{3}
\exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } |c_{n} - c_{q}| < \beta \; \forall n,q \geq n_{0} 
\end{equation}
We see :
\begin{equation} 
|(b_{m}-b_{p}) + (c_{n}-c_{q})| = |b_{m}-b_{p}| + |c_{n}-c_{q}| \text{ if } b_{m} - b_{p} \geq 0 \text{ and } c_{n} - c_{q} \geq 0
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{equation}
| (b_{m} - b_{p}) + (c_{n} - c_{q})| = |b_{m} - b_{p}| + |c_{n} - c_{q}| \text{ if } b_{m} - b_{p} \leq 0 \text{ and } c_{n} - c_{q} \leq 0
\end{equation}
and :
\begin{equation}
|(b_{m}-b_{p}) + (c_{n}-c_{q})| \leq |b_{m} - b_{p}| + |c_{n} - c_{q}| \text{ if } b_{m} - b_{p} \leq 0 \text{ and } c_{n} - c_{q} \geq 0
\end{equation}
with same inequality for $b_{m} - b_{p} \geq 0$ and $c_{n} - c_{q} \leq 0$.

So :
\begin{align}
\eqref{2} \text{ and } \eqref{3} \Rightarrow \exists (m_{0},n_{0}) \in \mathbb{N}^{2} \text{ such that } 
 | (b_{m} -b_{p}) + (c_{n}-c_{q})| & \leq |b_{m} - b_{p}| + |c_{n} - c_{q}| \; \forall (m,n),(p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0})\\
  | (b_{m} -b_{p}) + (c_{n}-c_{q})| & \leq 2\beta  \; \forall (m,n),(p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0})\\
 |a_{m,n} - a_{p,q}| & \leq 2\beta \; \forall (m,n),(p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0})
\end{align}
Since we can choose any $\beta > 0$ and find some $(m_{0},n_{0})$, let's choose $\beta < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ based on some choice
of $\epsilon > 0$. So :
\begin{equation}
\exists (m_{0},n_{0}) \in \mathbb{N}^{2} \text{ such that } |a_{m,n} - a_{p,q}| < \epsilon \; \forall (m,n),(p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0}) \; \checkmark
\end{equation}
and $(a_{m,n})$ is Cauchy. This means $(a_{m,n})$ is convergent. $\checkmark$

Now let's assume $a_{m,n}$ is convergent. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists (m_{0},n_{0}) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}$ such that  :
\begin{equation}
| a_{m,n} - a_{p,q} | < \epsilon \; \forall (m,n), (p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0})
\end{equation}
We see :
\begin{equation}
| a_{m,n} - a_{p,q}| = | (b_{m} + c_{n}) - (b_{p} + c_{q})| = | (b_{m} - b_{p}) + (c_{n} - c_{q}) |
\end{equation}
So for every $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists (m_{0},n_{0}) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}$ such that :
\begin{equation}
| (b_{m} - b_{p}) + (c_{n} - c_{q}) | < \epsilon \; \forall (m,n) , (p,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0})
\end{equation}
If $(b_{m})$ is divergent then $\exists \beta > 0$ such that for any $m_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ :
\begin{equation} \tag{4}\label{4}
| b_{m} - b_{p} | \geq \beta \text{ for some } m,p > m_{0}
\end{equation}
Now let's say $(c_{n})$ is convergent. Then we can always choose some $\gamma > 0$ such that $\exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  :
\begin{equation} \tag{5}\label{5} 
| c_{n} - c_{q} | < \gamma \; \forall n,q \geq n_{0}
\end{equation}
Let's choose some $\beta$ that satisfies \eqref{4} and let $m,p > m_{0}$ be such that
$| b_{m} - b_{p} | \geq \beta$. Also choose $\gamma > 0$ and $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfy \eqref{5} such that $\gamma = \frac{\beta}{2}$.
Then we have :
\begin{equation}
| (b_{m} - b_{p}) + (c_{n} - c_{q}) | \geq \frac{\beta}{2} \; \forall n,q \geq n_{0}
\end{equation}
Now choose $\epsilon < \frac{\beta}{2}$. So now we know that there exists $m,p > m_{0}$ and $n,q \geq n_{0}$ such that  :
\begin{equation}
| (b_{m} - b_{p}) + (c_{n} - c_{q}) | > \epsilon
\end{equation}
So when $(b_{m})$ is divergent and $(c_{n})$ is convergent, then $(a_{m,n})$ is divergent. $\checkmark$

By symmetry we must have the same result when $(b_{m})$ is convergent and $(c_{n})$ is divergent. $\checkmark$

Now need to prove $(a_{m,n})$ is divergent if both $(b_{m})$ and $(c_{n})$ are divergent.

Let's choose some $\beta > 0$ and $m,p,n,q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m,p > m_{0}$ and $n,q > n_{0}$ with :
\begin{align}
b_{m} & \geq b_{p}\\
c_{n} & \geq c_{q}\\
|b_{m} - b_{p}| & > \beta\\
|c_{n} - c_{q}| & > \beta
\end{align}
The fact that $(b_{m})$ and $(c_{n})$ are divergent ensures that such numbers exist.

We see :
\begin{align}
|(b_{m} - b_{p}) + (c_{n} - c_{q})|  & = | |b_{m} - b_{p}| + |c_{n} - c_{q}| |\\
     & = | b_{m} - b_{p} | + |c_{n} - c_{q}|\\
     & > 2 \beta
\end{align}
If we choose $\epsilon < \beta$ then we have :
\begin{equation}
| (b_{m} - b_{p}) + (c_{n} - c_{q}) | > \epsilon \text{ for some } (m,p),(n,q) \geq (m_{0},n_{0})
\end{equation}
So that $(a_{m,n})$ is divergent. $\checkmark$

So :
\begin{equation}
(a_{m,n}) \text{ is convergent } \Rightarrow (b_{m}) \text{ and } (c_{n}) \text{ are convergent } \; \checkmark
\end{equation}

Comment: The third implication is only valid under the assumption that the limits of $(b_m), (c_n)$ exist, which is actually what you want to prove. I think using the Cauchy definition would be the proper way to prove this.

Comment: The step from your second line to the third one (when you split the limits) isn't necessarily true. An idea: perhaps a contradiction argument could help here.